# How to integrate shopware 6 as headless service with Next js?

Tags: next.js, e-commerce, headless, shopware6

Is it possible to use Shopware 6 as a headless service with Nextjs.
For example, I am using BigCommerce on my nextjs projects, but I would like to use shopware if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Shopware 6 was designed as a headless platform first and foremost. The storefront it comes with is using the API internally as well.

There are multiple projects using Shopware as a headless environment. You can at look at them for reference.

- [Shopware PWA](https://github.com/vuestorefront/shopware-pwa) is an officially supported solution based on Vue Storefront
- [Shopware Frontends](https://github.com/shopware/frontends) is a framework specifically designed to build custom storefronts

For further reading see the documentation on the [Store API](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/api/store-api).

Comment: So, basically, it is a must to use Vue Storefront?
There is no option to use Shopware with Nextjs like I am using BigCommerce?

Comment: It is not a must at all. You can absolutely build your storefront with Nextjs using the Store API. I just mentioned the PWA built with Vue Storefront as proof that it is already being done, independently of the framework being used.

Comment: Oh cool, I found out. Thanks a lot. While I am a complete beginner in the Shopware world, I am a little bit confused. There are 2 API-s ( Store API and Admin API).  It is presented that Store API can be accessed from any HTTP-client ( Nextjs for example ) and for Admin API there are 2 SDK-s ( PHP and Python ). I am not sure am I understanding this right, but I can use Store API to fetch products, login users and all things needed on Frontend, and with Admin API I can write additional logic, or override existing endpoints?

Comment: You are right about the Store API. The Admin API is for creating products, updating orders and so on. As the name suggests all the administrative stuff.